# show sub menu in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using MvcSiteMap.Core.dll in order to show sitemap in tab form.I want to show sun menu (in tab form) just beneath the parent tab.How to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the submenu() call to work based on a selected node at the top level so I 'borrowed' code from eth source and wrote my own helper: http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=57379 you can then style the results anyway you want. Hope this helps